# Does lubridate really register leap seconds?

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I am looking at the R package `lubridate`. I am comparing its functions `days()` and `ddays()`. According to Wikipedia and to the global variable `.leap.seconds`, there is a leap second between 1997/06/30 and 1997/07/01. Therefore, I am expecting

```
ymd_hms("19970630 02:13:01", tz="GMT") + days(2) == ymd_hms("19970630 02:13:01", tz="GMT") + ddays(2)
```

to be FALSE, as `days(x)` merely increments the number of days by x, whereas `ddays(x)` increments the number of seconds by 86400x. However, the above statement returns TRUE. What am I missing?

Comment: Despite exporting `.leap.seconds`, R ignores leap seconds in date-time arithmetic to match the POSIX standard. You cannot define a `POSIXct` object representing the time `1997-06-30 23:59:60`, even though that time "happened" due to the leap second. It is explained in `?DateTimeClasses`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, that makes sense. Then I don't really understand why `lubridate` makes a difference between `days()` and `ddays()`. Shouldn't this be the same in every case then?

Comment: `ddays` makes a difference when there is a switch to daylight savings time in my experience.

Comment: I would suggest looking into how `lubridate` defines the following three [timespan classes](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/Timespan-class.html): `duration`, `interval`, and `period`. `days` returns a `period` object specifying an imprecise duration. `ddays` returns a `duration` object of exact duration.

Comment: `ddays` reflects our understanding of a day as 86400 seconds in "real time". `days` reflects our understanding of a day as the time from noon today and noon tomorrow, but that could be more or less than 86400 seconds of "real time", due to daylight savings time (as pointed out by @Sandwichnick) and leap seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on Mikael Jagan's and Sandwichnick's answers, I conclude the following:

`lubridate` ignores leap seconds in order to match the POSIX time standard. Therefore, `days()` and `ddays()` deliver the same results on a leap second day such as June 30th, 1997.

```r
> ymd_hms("19970630 02:13:01", tz = "UTC")+ddays(2) 
[1] "1997-07-02 02:13:01 UTC"
> ymd_hms("19970630 02:13:01", tz = "UTC")+days(2) 
[1] "1997-07-02 02:13:01 UTC"
```

However, `lubridate` does register daylight savings time, so `days()` and `ddays()` do differ in that case, as can be seen in the following example:

```r
> ymd_hms("20211030 14:45:06", tz = "Europe/Berlin")+days(1)
[1] "2021-10-31 14:45:06 CET"
> ymd_hms("20211030 14:45:06", tz = "Europe/Berlin")+ddays(1)
[1] "2021-10-31 13:45:06 CET"
```